# Last element not included in binary_search

Tags: c++, vector

I have to find if an element occurs in the array list. 
If yes, count the distinct number of elements and subtract it from the `n` which is the total size of the array.

My problem.
After running through a few cases, I noticed, the values at the last index aren't read.
For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int test;
    cin>>test;
    for(int i=0;i<test;i++) {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        vector<int> ar(n);
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) {
            cin>>ar[j];
        }
        int c=0;
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) {
            if(binary_search(ar.begin(),ar.end(),j)) {
                c++;
            }       
        }
        cout<<n-c<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test Case

```
1
3
0 1 2
```

Answer should be `1` as 
1 and 2 are found so, `c=0+2=2` which implies `cout<<n-c<<endl;` = `3-2=1`

Answer according to this code,comes out to be `2`

Not able to find where the problem lies.

Comment: Binary search is for *sorted ranges*. Yours most probably isn't.

Comment: Besides, your are looking at the wrong algorithms. `std::sort` and `std::unique` are of interest here.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, it's for sorted ranges. Isn't `0 1 2` a sorted range? And i'll look into those

Comment: Yes, `0 1 2` is sorted. But what if you get a test case of `3 6 18 7 22`?

Comment: you loop from j=1 to n. That means that the first value is stored in the second position of `ar` and the last value is not saved at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just seem to have a bug in your code:

In line ~15

```
for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
```

`ar` goes from 0 to n-1, not 1 to n. So the last value you are writing will have undefined behavior.

In your case, you get trash value for the first element, in my case it just crashed.

Solving the issue, the result is 1 as expected.

Comment: But aren't arrays open to interpretation? I mean we can index them both from `0` or from `1` depending on preference. Isn't same the case with vectors?

Comment: Not that I know about: all, arrays, vectors, std::array, etc. goes from 0 to size()-1. Or what do you means with "open to interpretation"?